# distributed TensorFlow train.Supervisor RuntimeError on stop

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am testing a distributed TensorFlow, almost identical to [inception_distributed_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py) (synchronous data parallelism) but using the default [mnist dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/index.html) of the basic examples.

For the master worker (only), for `sv = tf.train.Supervisor` the closing `sv.stop()` gives `RuntimeError: ('Coordinator stopped with threads still running: %s', 'Thread-4')`.

At the same time on the `ps` node I see logs `Variable:0: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed`, and equally for Variables 1-7, although interestingly not for Variable 8 defined as `global_step = tf.Variable(0)` and passed into `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`, method `minimize` as `global_step`.

Does this error ring a bell to anyone? I really can't see where my logic differs from that of [inception_distributed_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py)

Comment: Exactly the same problem! sv not exit correctly!